# ftp_put só funciona uma vez

Tags: php, ftp

Quando utilizo o *script* abaixo ele só funciona na primeira vez que roda. Quando tento novamente não envia o arquivo, apenas escreve localmente. Por quê? Estou usando `ftp_close`, não é suficiente?

Quando altero o host ele funciona só para a primeira vez.

```
//Definição do arquivo local
$arq = "p";
$arq .= date("YmdHis");
$arq .=".txt";
//Escreve o arquivo local
file_put_contents($arq,$conteudo_file);
//Conecta no server remoto e loga
$dados = array(
"host" => "ftp.testes.com",
"usuario" => "user",
"senha" => "password");
$fconn = ftp_connect($dados["host"]);
ftp_login($fconn, $dados["usuario"], $dados["senha"]);
//envia arquivo para o server remoto
ftp_chdir($fconn, "DataIn");
ftp_put($fconn, $arq, $arq, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($fconn);
unlink($arq);
```

Comment: o script é só mesmo isso? Dá algum erro?

Comment: Provavelmente alguma da funções `ftp_???` está gerando erro mas você está ignorando-os. Mande imprimir o retorno destas funções e coloque aqui o que está acontecendo (você deve [edit] a pergunta). De qq forma leia a documentação, veja exemplos, não é assim que usa essas funções.

Comment: Constatei que o código funciona, porém demora até 50min para o arquivo "aparecer" no server remoto.